# Schedule in AWS Instance Scheduler not working as planned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/) running in my account and have a custom period that isn't working as planned and I don't understand why. I have a period that is part of a schedule and the intent is to stop instances at 6:00PM on Mon-Fri with no restart so they have to be manually started. Here is the json:

```
  {
    "type": {"S": "period"},
    "name": {"S": "weekday-shutdown-1800"},
    "description": {"S": "shutdown 6:00pm daily with no start"},
    "endtime": {"S": "17:59"},
    "weekdays": {"SS": ["mon-fri"]}
  })
```

What is happening is the instances are shutting down at 6:00PM on the correct days of Mon-Fri. The problem is that they are starting at 00:00 Mon-Fri as well which we don't want.

Can someone assist with what I am missing please?

Comment: FYI, I wrote a Simple Lambda Stopinator that might be suitable for your situation: [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj)

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to stay with the AWS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with AWS and testing the solution was pretty simple. Set the begintime and the endtime to the same value and it works perfectly.

It was starting them at midnight based on the weekdays value. It wouldn't start them on Sat or Sun because they were outside the running window however with no begintime specified it used the weekdays value to start the instances at midnight on each weekday.

Removing the weekdays value would have also worked to shut them down at 6:00PM every day, not just weekdays. In that case it also would not have started them at midnight because there were no other conditions to evaluate.